# Как удалить один из выбранных файлов в input type=file?

Tags: html, javascript

Есть форма, в ней `input type="file" multiple`. Можно выбрать сразу несколько файлов. Вопрос в том, как средствами js можно удалить один из файлов? К примеру, по его filename или по индексу.

Answer (score 2):

Советую Вам использовать [FancyUpload](http://digitarald.de/project/fancyupload/). Очень классная вещь, позволяет загружать множество файлов средствами AJAX, удалять из списка загрузок любые файлы, по моему использует библиотеку JavaScript - Mootools. Очень прост в установке. Показывает на каждый файл **progress bar** загрузки. Работает стабильно. Демо можно посмотреть, если перейти по ссылке выше. Надеюсь, помог решить Вам, Вашу проблему!

**UPD** Данное решение является кроссбраузерным!! Поддерживает Internet Explorer 6+, Opera 9, Firefox 1.5+ and Safari 3+.

Comment: + Выглядит в 100 раз эффектнее, чем input type="file" multiple, так что очень рекомендую Вам его использовать!